# Display Unstructured Object as an Example Response in SpringDoc

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc

I have a class which will represent the **BadRequestResponse **and it will contain every attribute and the reason of validation for it and the number of attribute are not determined for me so I use `Map<String,List<String>>` for representing each atrribute and failed validation reason

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class BadRequestResponse {

    @Schema(type = "string" , example = "Validation Failed")
    private String message;

    
    private Map<String,List<String>> failed_validation_attributes;
}
```

and when i call API in case of failed validation it will gives me

```
{
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "failed_validation_attributes": {
        "lastName": [
            "Second Name Should Not Be Null or Empty"
        ],
        "firstName": [
            "First Name Should Not Be Null or Empty"
        ]
    }
}
```

and when i use this class in SpringDoc it gives me
[Swagger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiIDp.jpg)

I would like to view example resonse as in swagger doc

```
{
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "failed_validation_attributes": {
        "lastName": [
            "Second Name Should Not Be Null or Empty"
        ],
        "firstName": [
            "First Name Should Not Be Null or Empty"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below.

```java
    @ArraySchema(arraySchema = @Schema(
            example = "{\"lastName\": [ \"Second Name Should Not Be Null or Empty\" ], \"firstName\": [ \"First Name Should Not Be Null or Empty\"]}"))
    private Map<String, List<String>> failed_validation_attributes;
```